# Firebase Cloud Storage: permission denied. could not perform this operation firebase when retrieving downloadURL

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a function that successfully uploads an image to my cloud storage bucket.

With another function I want to get the URL of the image to show it on my page (With `<img.../>`)

```
getImageUrl(id: string) {
    return this.storageRef.child('X/' + id ).getDownloadURL();
```

But when I do this.. I get an 'invalid' URL and when I copy the URL and go to it, I get the following message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"
  }
}
```

I read somewhere that this might be because there is no token attached in the URL, but how can I enable this?

Answer (score 27):

The last couple of days I have been trying to understand Firebase Storage rules and I don't know why but when I separate rules for writing and for reading like this for example:

```
allow write: if request.auth != null && request.resource.size < 3 * 1024 * 1024;
allow read: if true;
```

the code works great and I can write and read using getDownloadURL(), but when I use them together like this:

```
allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.resource.size < 3 * 1024 * 1024;
```

I got the same error as you:

```
{
  "error": {
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"
  }
```

}

I can write when using them together, but when I try to read the file using getDownloadURL(), the issue appears. Maybe you could try separating the rules as I mention and see if it works. I hope it solves your problem. Also, don't forget that the rules are **live after 5 minutes** **from the moment** you set them. Good luck.

Comment: That is probably because the read request doesn't HAVE any request resource, and therefore `request.resource.size` will always be null, which is not smaller than 3 MB. And so the combined condition is always false for read requests.

Answer (score 6):

You have to set Storage Security Rules, read more about this [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start?authuser=1)

Comment: Thank you so much, saved me another hour

Answer (score 3):

Just faced similar issue with my project, if anyone is still struggling with it, you have to provide proper rules for your Cloud Storage from the Firebase console.
Checkout [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start?authuser=1) link to get full detail of the rools.

If you are uploading any object on your storage, you will require to add `write` rule under Firebase console > Storage > Rules.

Comment: Thank you so much, saved me another hour

Answer (score 2):

I've faced the same issues with access to my storage files in my iOS project. I don't have any custom security rules. Just what's default in configuration. Breaking rules to new lines helped!

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow write: if request.auth != null; 
      allow read;
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know if this is some firebase bug but it helped:)

Answer (score 1):

just use this rule for image

```
service firebase.storage {
 match /b/{bucket}/o {
 match /images/{imageId} {
  // Only allow uploads of any image file that's less than 5MB
  allow write: if request.resource.size < 5 * 1024 * 1024
               && request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*');
    }
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Separating read and write in different lines makes the issue go away, plus in your url you can just append ?alt=media to render it on screen.

allow write: if true; //your conditino

allow read: if true;

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the getDownloadURL method. This will allow you to obtain the URL needed to download the image or for reference in your own html.

See the reference documentation below:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url

Comment: I'm using the getDownloadURL in my getImageUrl method.

Comment: OK. My bad. Perhaps the rules have been set to require authentication? Also check the status in the file location section on the console to make sure the URL is created. I did not need a token.

Comment: Hmm, my user, who gets to see the page, is authenticated so I assumed that the authentication was ok on that end. (I had indeed a rule stating that authentication is required).

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I accidentally delete the files before so it needs to show the **File not found** message but don't know why it was showing the **Permission denied** message.

Answer (score 0):

i had date condition issue. Extended the date to december

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:**
Although this was a temporary fix but it comes with security vulnerability (refer to @Joao Gavazzi's comment).

I was able to solve this by changing the FirebaseStorage security rules from default to:

```
    rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't do that. Anyone with your storage reference will be able to flood it with data causing you your bill to skyrocket.

Comment: really sorry hadn't thought from that point of view.. Thank you so much  !