# read only firebase storage rules tab

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to set the rules tab of my firebase object to read only.

When I take off the write parcel I got an error on my python when trying to add files to my storage.

Below is my code

```py
import firebase_admin

config={
    "apiKey": "xxx",
    "authDomain": "xxx",
    "databaseURL": "xxx",
    "projectId": "xxx",
    "storageBucket": "xxx",
    "messagingSenderId": "xxx",
    "appId": "xxx",
    "measurementId": "xxx"
}
# Initialize connection to firebase_admin

firebase = firebase_admin.initialize_app(config)
storage = firebase.storage()

path_on_cloud ="Data quality report/Data quality report.py"
path_local = "Data_quality_report.py"
storage.child(path_on_cloud).put(path_local)
```

My rules tab is

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Do you guys know how to fix this problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you also please add the error that you received. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Sijan! Thank you for your response. The error is 
```"code": 403,
    "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"``` I believe is because of the put method used in .put(path_local)

Comment: It does look like a permission issue, but as mentioned you already have a correct storage rules as defined by firebase security rules at https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start?authuser=1. 

Could you confirm if you have the correct permission for the project?

This however looks like a common issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50432995/firebase-cloud-storage-permission-denied-could-not-perform-this-operation-fire

Comment: Does this help https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase/issues/274#issuecomment-619327970?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, do you know with what the idToken should be replaced in 
the example you provided me?

Comment: Here is a detail explanation, https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#authentication .
You need to login the user with `user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)` and pass the value of user['idToken'].


However i see a download function, https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#download, is this something you probably wanted in the first place ?

I would suggest for  you to use a custom token https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#custom-tokens, so that you do not expose your email and password :) .

Comment: The error simply looks like you did the firebase config but you did not authenticate, try debugging that part .

Comment: Thanks for your support Sijan, I am new to Firebase and it is pretty confusing. Do I have to add the authentification script in my python code or directly on my rules tab?

Comment: You should do it after the config. 
However could you check if you have actually logged in first in your machine? with https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli

looking at this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1eskLk0exg, might help you.

Comment: This is the same tutorial I have started with, i will add the authentification script and keep you updated shortly

Answer (score 2):

Don't initialize it that way!
You are using the `firebase_admin` package which using the Firebase Admin SDK. To initialize it create a new service account key file which is then used for initializing.

Admin does what it sounds like it would do. It has all privileges.

Refer the official docs for proper explanation on setup. (I am really bad at explaining things).
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start#python

Comment: Thanks for your response Shardul, Do you know how to create a new service account key? Do I have to create a new project? I have a key from an older project, can I use the same?

Comment: No, each project has a different service key. To get a key go to:- `Settings > Service Accounts` and click the `Generate New Private Key` button. The keys are private so don't push them to git, etc.